# Button click event fires only once .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, event-handling

The first time the button is pressed, the eventhandler is called and a popupwindow appears. After exiting that popupwindow, the second time the button is clicked, the eventhandler isn't called at all. I have debugged the code quite a bit without finding anything 'statewise' that should ruin the code, thus only providing this brief bit of code. Please tell me if you believe more resources are needed to pinpoint this problem.

```
     <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReferenceControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="DynamicForm.DynamicGenerator.Controls.ReferenceControl" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

    <%@ Register Src="~/DynamicGenerator/Controls/SearchControl.ascx" TagName="SearchControl" TagPrefix="dyncontrols" %>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Välj" onclick="btn_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="popUpControl" runat="server" TargetControlID="popupDummyTarget" PopupControlID="pnlSearch" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowSearch();
    }

void ShowSearch()
    {
                    //some stuff
        popUpControl.Show();
    }
```

**How can I make my button listen to my requests?**

I have tried adding DataBind() in the eventhandler, unfortunatly that didn't work.

UPDATE1:
The second click generates this error in firebug:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001c (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/spy.js :: callPageHandler :: line 744" data: no]

Comment: What causes the popup? it's not clear from your code.

Comment: remove RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional"... or else remove updatepanel it makes sometime problem..

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled?

Comment: @jAX: Thanks for the suggestions, tried them, but didn't work.

@CrapHands: No, not that I know of.

Comment: Are you sure its not an issue with the popup instead of actually being an issue with the button click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up Firebug and see if you're getting any JavaScript errors after the initial click.

Comment: Aha! Didn't find any error on the initial click, but I did find something on the second: check the updated initial post for the error message.